# como criar numeros em variaveis diferente no javascript JS

Tags: javascript

Estou desenvolvendo um site para treinar multiplicação em matemática. Nele, tenho uma pergunta aleatória. Por exemplo, (12x12) e, para cada pergunta tenho que gerar três números aleatórios, onde, apenas um deles é a respostas correta. No caso do exemplo 12x12, um dos 3 números tem que ser o valor 144;

Código JavaScript abaixo:

```
// essas são as opções.
let option1 = 0;
let option2 = 0;
let option3 = 0;

function geraOptions() {
    **gerando os numeros aleatorios numberLeft*numberRight.**
    const numberLeft = Math.floor(Math.random(1) * 10);
    const numberRight = Math.floor(Math.random(1) * 10);

    const multiplicação = numberLeft * numberRight;

    // agora eu preciso de algo que gere 3 três numeros com apenas um deles sendo o valor correto da multiplicação e os outros 2 sendo incorretos, mas a cada reload da pagina tem que ser criado em um lugar diferente exemplo:
}
geraOptions();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá criei uma função que atende ao que vc gostaria, mas certamente vc vai refinar conforme sua necessidade, mas de forma geral deve te ajudar pelo menos a encontrar algo que seja ideal. Abaixo segue ela com comentários:

```
   //num1 - Primeiro numero da expressao
    //num2 -  segundo numero da expressao
    //qtdAlternativas -  qtde de alternativas que você quer q a pergunta venha a ter
    // essa função pega esses 3 argumentos e gera um array de json onde vc tera a 
    // alternativa se e correta ou nao e o valor da alternativa
    // nesse padrao: [{val: 15, correto: false}, {val:10, correto: true},]
    function geraRespostas(num1, num2, qtdAlternativas){

    // aqui quero saber de antemao qual sera o valor correto
    var correct =  num1 * num2;
    
    /* a razao por querer alternativas - 1  é pq ja temos uma alternativa q no caso seria a correta */
    var randAlternativas = qtdAlternativas  - 1;
    
    // array onde armazenaremos as alternativas inclusive claro a correta
    var arrAlternativas = [];
    
  // loop para gerar as alternativas aleatorias no caso sao no range de 1 a 1000
    for(var i = 0; i < randAlternativas; i++){
        var aleat = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
    
        // nao queremos gerar uma alternativa q tenha valor igual a correta
        while(aleat == correct){
            aleat = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
        }
        // colocamos nosssas alternativas incorretas 
        arrAlternativas.push({val: aleat, correto: false});
        
    }
    
    // colocamos nosssa alternativa correta
    arrAlternativas.push({val: correct, correto: true});
    
// abaixo vamos apenas embaralhar as alternativas    
    var currentIndex = arrAlternativas.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;


  while (0 !== currentIndex) {


    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // realizar trocas de posicoes pra embaralhar
    temporaryValue = arrAlternativas[currentIndex];
    arrAlternativas[currentIndex] = arrAlternativas[randomIndex];
    arrAlternativas[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }
  // e devolver o array de alternativas
  return arrAlternativas;
}

//Experimente!
console.log(geraRespostas(12,12,3));
//(possivel resultado)
//[{val: 200, correto: false}, {val: 144, correto: true}, {val: 386, correto: false}]
```

Comment: cara, era isso mesmo, muito obrigado me ajudou muito, eu não estava conseguindo embaralhar as respostar porque sempre retornava em um única posição.

Comment: como eu posso chamar os numeros do JSON?, por tenho <p> <p> <p>, quero que fique 1 valor em cada tag P

Comment: Pow cara que bom q te ajudou. EU sempre acho bacana achar ao q eu preciso aqui. Um hora precisamos retribuir. Sobre os Numeros do JSON, repare que é um array entao quando vc interar sobre ele com um for(key in oArray) vc gera o numero a partir da posição no array (key + 1) pq em js as chaves começam em Zero

Comment: vdd mano, agora entendi como pegar os numeros, obrigado dnv!

Comment: Tamo junto maninho dev.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que seja isso que você deseja fazer:

```
function generateOptions(param1, param2, qtde) {

    do {
        var multi = [], original_calc = 0, calc = 0;
        for (var i=0; i < qtde; i++) {
             var n1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10),
                 n2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
                 calc = n1 * n2;
             if (n1 != n2 && n1 > 0 && n2 > 0) {    
               multi.push({numbers:[n1, n2], result:calc})
             }
        }

        original_calc = (param1 * param2);

    } while(calc != original_calc && calc > 0 && multi.length < qtde);

    var original = {
           numbers:[param1, param2],
           result:original_calc
    }

    return {
       result_params:original,
       others:multi,
       total_send: qtde
    }
}
console.log(generateOptions(12, 12, 3));
```

Se quiser melhorar, pode pegar o tamanho do número de casas decimais e colocar o randômico baseado em seu comprimento:

```
function pad(str, length) {
  const resto = length - String(str).length;
  return str+'0'.repeat(resto > 0 ? resto : '0');
}

function setSizeRandomic(param)
   var str =(param).toString(),
       leng = str.length,
       pads = pad(Math.floor(Math.random() * leng), leng),
       casas = parseInt(pads);
     return Math.floor(Math.random() * casas); 
}
```

Bastaria chamar assim dentro do primeiro método:

```
function generateOptions(param1, param2, qtde) {
    
        do {
            var multi = [], original_calc = 0, calc = 0;
            for (var i=0; i < qtde; i++) {
                var n1 = setSizeRamdomic(param1),
                    n2 = setSizeRamdomic(param2);
                    calc = n1 * n2;
                 if (n1 != n2 && n1 > 0 && n2 > 0) {    
                   multi.push({numbers:[n1, n2], result:calc})
                 }
            }
    
            original_calc = (param1 * param2);
    
        } while(calc != original_calc && calc > 0 && multi.length < qtde);
    
        var original = {
               numbers:[param1, param2],
               result:original_calc
        }
    
        return {
           result_params:original,
           others:multi,
           total_send: qtde
        }
    }
    console.log(generateOptions(12, 12, 3));
```